# ActiveAdmin + CarrierWave & Multiple Uploads: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, carrierwave

Good day.

I'm working on adding multiple uploads to my rails 5 app with ActiveAdmin & Carrierwave.

As of now, I'm receiving the following error:

```js
no implicit conversion of nil into String

def workfile_path(for_file=original_filename)
   File.join(CarrierWave.tmp_path, @cache_id, version_name.to_s, for_file)
end
```

Here is how I'm setting up my files.

```
# admin/photo.rb  
permit_params :description, {image: []}, :taken, :image_cache, :tag_list, :title

form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
 f.inputs "New Image" do
   f.input :title, placeholder: "Drinking Coffee", hint: "Reference title for photo.", required: true
   f.input :image, as: :file, id: "preview_this_image",
                            input_html: {
                              multiple: true,
                            }
   f.input :taken, label: "Taken on:", as: :date_select, hint: "When was the photo taken?"
 end
 f.actions
end

#schema
create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.datetime "taken"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.string   "title"
  t.json     "image"
end
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy to miss 's' in the docs. Check the mounting in your model. For multiple files, you need to `mount_uploaders` ( multiple) instead of `mount_uploader`(singular).

Comment: That's it! Ugh - such a small thing.